# Error in my Python code: elseif error in Python

Tags: python-3.x

below code is not working

```
N = int(input())
print("Enter number",N)
 if(N%2!=0):
 print("Weird")
  elif (N%2==0) and (N>=2 and N<=5):
      print("Not Weird")
      elif(N%2==0) and (N>=6 and N<=20):
          print("Weird")
         else:
         print("Not Weird")
```

I am getting below error:

```
File "solution.py", line 7
elif (N%2==0) and (N>=2 and N<=5):
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Python is very strict with its syntax, make sure that your `if`-`elif`-`else` all start on the same column.

Comment: your code has indentation issues, first resolve the.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your indentation, you cannot start `elif` without `if`, you should always start `if` and then `elif`. you can check for condition as below:

```
print("Enter number")
N = int(input())
if(N%2!=0):
    print("Weird")
elif (N%2==0) and (N>=2 and N<=5):
    print("Not Weird")
elif(N%2==0) and (N>=6 and N<=20):
    print("Weird")
else:
     print("Not Weird")
```

For your coding conventions, you can always look on to [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thank you dip bazz

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with indentation.

```
N = int(input())
print("Enter number",N)
if(N%2!=0):
   print("Weird")
elif (N%2==0) and (N>=2 and N<=5):
   print("Not Weird")
elif(N%2==0) and (N>=6 and N<=20):
   print("Weird")
else:
   print("Not Weird")
```